# Is Star Trek: Picard mixing with the Kelvin Timeline

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-picard

I recently saw a blurb about the new ST:P series starting next year...

One thing they mention is that Romulus (Romulan Home World) was destroyed in a super nova.

Wait I thought that event was in the new Kelvin timeline. Are they going to say it also happened in the ST:TOS & ST:TNG timeline also?

If so that would make the "Kelvin Timeline" Reboot NOT a changed timeline/future, but a completely different reality (Like the Mirror Universe.) Otherwise the whole TOS and TNG would not have taken place and we would not now have ST:P.

Comment: The destruction of Romulus happened in the Prime Timeline, shortly after the end of Star Trek: Nemesis. It was Nero returning to the past that created the new "Kelvin" timeline going forward

Comment: Ahh, I get it now... as you said, The attempts to stop the nova are what created the Kelvin timeline. (Probably better referred to as the Kelvin Universe as the Prime Timeline is clearly still continuing instead of being overwritten by the Kelvin timeline,)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was confusing the source of the Kelvin Timeline (Kelvin Universe) and did not realize that the destruction of Romulus occurred in the Prime Timeline.

It was Spock's failed attempt to stop the destruction of Romulus, that produced the Kelvin Universe.